# Using Expressions to perform string operations (contains, startwith,...)

Tags: vb.net, string, linq, silverlight-4.0, expression

I'm trying to make a generic filter for data overviews and I've come across expressions. In that example, some expressions are used to do comparisons:

```
return Expression.Equal(left, right);
return Expression.GreaterThan(left, right);
return Expression.GreaterThanOrEqual(left, right);
return Expression.LessThan(left, right);
return Expression.LessThanOrEqual(left, right);
return Expression.NotEqual(left, right);
```

For dates and integer values they are all I need, but when it comes to strings, users will need other filter functionality. So I'd like to add "contains and startswith" possibilities. But looking at "Expression.", it doesn't give me that possibility. I was gonna add some custom Expressions but I cannot find anything relevant to that. The expression returned are used in this piece of code:

```
Expression.Call(typeof (Queryable),"Where",new[] {list.ElementType},list.Expression,Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(exp, new[] {pe}));
```

Does someone has any experience doing this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Contains` and `StartsWith` are not operator they are simply methods of the class `String` you would use `Experssion.Call` to include the use of these.

Answer (score 0):

You do not have to add custom Expressions. Just write the dynamic linq expression in the `Where` method of the object which implements `IQueryable`.
Like this:

```
...
using System.Linq.Dynamic;
...

string searchKeyword = "ant";
IQueryable<Person> collection = GetPersonCollection();
collection.Where(string.Format("FirstName.Contains('{0}')"), searchKeyword);
```